# Javascript callback design: is it OK to have side effects?

Tags: javascript, callback

Consider this javascript function:

```
function(){
    var someArr = [...];
    var someObj = {...};
    someArr.forEach(function(item){
        if (matchItem(item)){
            someObj.callMethod(item.someProp);
        }
    });
}
```

Assuming that given code works correctly, let's take a look at it's design. As you can notice, `someArr.forEach` is passed a callback function. Meanwhile, object `someObj` belongs to the scope of that callback. So from inside the callback function we can manipulate `someObj`.

I.e., in this case the callback produces side effects.

We could also bind `someObj` to `this` object of the callback:

```
function(){
    var someArr = [...];
    var someObj = {...};
    someArr.forEach(
        function(item){
            if (matchItem(item)){
                this.callMethod(item.someProp);
            }
        },
        someObj
    );
}
```

Again, we are producing some side effects here, though in more explicit manner. In general, this approach can not be considered functional, because it violates the no-side-effects principle.

How should we design code in such situations? Which way is more robust? What are the best practices?

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest asking this on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there a way to move this question to programmers.stackexchange.com or should I delete it here and post new question there?

Comment: Yes, it is alright to have side effects in JavaScript. As a thumb rule, it's better not to have side effects. However, immutability is not always practical. Even languages like Haskell which are pure by default allow you to have side-effects (you just have to explicit about the side effects). By the way, your code is only side-effectful if `callMethod` is side-effectful.